# Difference between "technical criteria" and "functional criteria"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between *technical criteria* and *functional criteria*?

> Website architecture is an approach to the design and planning of websites which, like architecture itself, involves **technical**, aesthetic and **functional** criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In software development, including website design and especially web applications, *functional* is concerned with how things will function from a user's perspective, whereas *technical* is concerned with the inner workings of how that functional component is delivered.

So a functional description might be:

> When a user clicks the up arrow next to an answer, this adds 1 to the
>   answer's score. It also adds 10 points to the answerer's reputation
>   and records this in the user's activity log. If necessary the answers are moved
>   to ensure they stay sorted by score.

Whereas a technical description would mention the technologies used to do this (such as jquery and ajax), which data tables are updated, which functions are called, etc. In essence the two describe the same functions but from different perspectives - the functional description is from the user's perspective and the technical description is from the software developer's perspective.

Comment: Couldn't technical criteria also include hardware and infrastructure like networking?

Comment: @jimreed Yes, absolutely - although that's slightly less likely in the context of a standalone website

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is very thin difference.

`Functional` in this stands for `process` or `functionality` whereas

`Technical` relates with software.

Remember `functional` can be used in any field while `technical` is used generally with the field relates with technology.

Comment: Technical can relate to hardware and actually to any requirement or criteria that is related to technologies that are used. Functional is related to the functions performed by the system. There is an overlap, but when looking at criteria or requirements it is useful to take extreme conceptual positions.